# IF ELSE Generator based on values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame which contains if else conditions in columns Region, minage, and maxage. See df below.

```
   Seasoning Region minage maxage
1 mths:36-47      A     36     47
2 mths:24-35      A     24     35
3 mths:12-23      A     12     23
4 mths:36-47      B     36     47
5 mths:24-35      B     24     35
6 mths:12-23      B     12     23
```

I want to generate the following IF ELSE conditions in automated fashion within function as I have more than 40-50 conditions in my actual dataset. In short, I don't want to type if else conditions manually. Format of if condition -

```
(seasoning >= minage) & (seasoning <= maxage) & (Region == value_Region_column)
```

Function

```
bx_is <- function(seasoning = NULL, Region = NULL) {
  Bx = if ((seasoning >= 36) & (seasoning <= 47) & (Region == 'A')) {trans1} 
  else if ((seasoning >= 24) & (seasoning <= 35) & (Region == 'A')) {trans2}
  else if ((seasoning >= 12) & (seasoning <= 23) & (Region == 'A')) {trans3}
  else if ((seasoning >= 36) & (seasoning <= 47) & (Region == 'B')) {trans4}
  else if ((seasoning >= 24) & (seasoning <= 35) & (Region == 'B')) {trans5}
  else if ((seasoning >= 12) & (seasoning <= 23) & (Region == 'B')) {trans6}
  return(data.matrix(Bx))
}

bx_is(seasoning=28, Region = 'B')
```

**Input Df**

```
mx = structure(list(Seasoning = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("mths:12-23", "mths:24-35", "mths:36-47"), class = "factor"), 
Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
minage = c(36L, 24L, 12L, 36L, 24L, 12L), maxage = c(47L, 35L, 23L, 47L, 35L, 23L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**Note** In bx_is( ) function shown above, trans1...trans6 are 6 different matrices. I want to use matrix based on condition of this function in loop of 22M iterations. **I can't apply filter as it takes some processing and slows in 22M iterations.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df = mx %>% mutate(res=paste0("trans", row_number()))

bx_is <- function(seasoning, region) {
  r = df %>% filter(Region == region, minage <= seasoning, maxage >= seasoning)
  get(r$res)
}
```

It creates a dataframe `df` which appends a `res` column corresponding to the result to output for each condition (row).

The function `bx_is` filters the dataframe depending on the conditions and outputs the `res` value for the row respecting the condition.

**EDIT**
Since it is slower (even when using `data.table`) than using `if else` statements, we can generate the same code and evaluate it with:

```
f <- function() {
  s = "bx_is <- function(seasoning = NULL, Region = NULL) {"

  for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
    r = paste0("((seasoning >= ",
               df[i, ]$minage,
               ") & (seasoning <= ",
               df[i, ]$maxage,
               ') & (Region == "',
               df[i, ]$Region,
               '")) {',
               df[i, ]$res,
               "}")
    if (i == 1) {
      s = paste0(s, " Bx = if ", r)
    } else {
      s = paste0(s, "\n else if ", r)
    }
  }

  s = paste0(s, "\n return(data.matrix(Bx))}")
  s
}
eval(parse(text=f()))
```

Comment: trans1...trans6 are 6 different matrices. I want to use matrix based on this function in loop of 22M iterations.

Comment: I just edited: you can get the matrix by its name with ``get(r$res)``. For instance ``get("trans1")`` is ``trans1``.

Comment: I can't apply filter as it takes some processing and slows in 22M iterations

Comment: I don't think it is the filtering which is slow, it should not be really faster if all the conditions are writen manually (you only have 50 rows and this processing is done in C++ when using dplyr). Your for loop in R over so much elements is what makes it slow.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested filtering and without filtering. Filtering is atleast 10 times slower. IF conditions need not process anything.

Comment: @john You are right, it is about 10 times slower :( Please see the last edit.